# ravenDB + python not saving

Tags: python, ravendb

I'm currently editing existing documents in my ravenDB instance.
The main issue i'm facing is that i get no errors but no changes are saved.
I'm using the following code :

```
    #in init method

        self.store = document_store.documentstore(url=self.dbURL, database=self.dbInUse)
        self.store.initialize()

    def someMethodToSaveData(self, id, newTextField="")

        with self.store.open_session() as session:
             doc = session.load(id)
             doc.newTextField=newTextField
             session.store(doc,id)
             session.save_changes()
```

thanks

edit: added session.save_changes() in this code. testing, but i have that line in another project and I'm facing the same issue with it.

Comment: You don't need to call `store` on the session for an object that was loaded in the session. That is likely causing it the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to call the method **session.save_changes()** so that the the database transaction completes:

```
 #in init method

        self.store = document_store.documentstore(url=self.dbURL, database=self.dbInUse)
        self.store.initialize()

    def someMethodToSaveData(self, id, newTextField="")

        with self.store.open_session() as session:
             doc = session.load(id)
             doc.newTextField=newTextField
             session.store(doc,id)
             session.save_changes() # this call is important
```

I found this information in the offical  [RavenDB documentation](https://github.com/ravendb/RavenDB-Python-Client):

Comment: I edited my code and will restest. But I have the same issue with another piece of code that contains the save_changes() call.

Comment: another source of problems could be if that you are overwriting an existing (not to a database saved) session with a new session and therefore the database transaction never completes.

Comment: Hi Neil after adding save_changes() the code start to work?

Comment: After adding save_changes() the code start to work?
And could you please send us the other piece of code that have the same issue?

And like Ayende Rahien said you don't need to store the entity again the save_changes() know that you have changes in the session. FYI this isn't the problem

Comment: Indeed, i should avoid storing an object that is already in DB.